# Ruby on Rails - Rubyのversion変更ができない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv

こんにちわ。プログラミング初心者です。
Rubyのversion変更ができず困っています。

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
```

と出るのですが、
下記を実行するとエラーが出てしまい、rails tutorialが進みません。
どなたか知見のある方アドバイスいただけると嬉しいです。

```
rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[rbenv](/questions/tagged/rbenv)タグがあるので rbenv を使って ruby をインストールしている前提とします。
おそらく `rails` コマンドは rbenv によってインストールされた ruby ではなく、別の場所にインストールされている Ruby 2.0.0 でインストールされた rails を実行しているのが原因です。
rbenv によってインストールされる rails のほうが前になるように PATH を設定する必要があります。

例えば `~/.rbenv` 以下に rbenv がインストールされており、PATH が以下である場合

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/itochan/.rbenv/shims:/Users/itochan/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
```

rails コマンドを実行したときに `/usr/bin/rails` や `/usr/local/bin/rails` ではなく `/Users/itochan/.rbenv/shims/rails` が実行されます。

PATH の設定方法は通常シェルの設定ファイルに

```
export PATH=~/foo/bar:$PATH
```

などと書きますが、 rbenv であれば

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

をシェルの設定ファイル（`.bashrc` など）に追記すると PATH が追加されます。